# show multiple alert in one message in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have multiple required field controls on my aspx form.

Now what I want is to show the validation message on button click if anything is not filled or checked.

**I want it on one message in JQuery.**

Here is my JQuery code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
            if (!validateTitle() || !validatePrefix() || !validateTextBoxes()) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
        function validateTitle() {
            if ($("#ddlTitle").val() > "0") {
                if ($("#ddlTitle").val() == "1104" && $("#txtTitle").val() === "") {
                    alert("Please enter the text in other title");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('Please select the title');
                return false;
            }
        }
        function validatePrefix() {
            if ($("#ddlPrefix").val() > "0") {
                if ($("#ddlPrefix").val() == "1110" && $("#txtPrefix").val() === "") {
                    alert("Please enter the text in other prefix");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('Please select the prefix');
                return false;
            }
        }
        function validateTextBoxes() {
            if ($("#txtFirstName").val() === "") {
                alert('First name is required');
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtMiddleName").val() === "") {
                alert('Middle name is required');
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtLastName").val() === "") {
                alert('Last name is required');
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtFatherName").val() === "") {
                alert('Father name is required');
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtCurrentCompany").val() === "") {
                alert('Current company is required');
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtDateofJoin").val() === "") {
                alert('Date is required');
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtCurrentExp").val() === "") {
                alert('Current Experience is required');
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with the HTML as well. We'll be able to help you easily and in a much better way.

Comment: @mechanicals: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/onkwhhv3/) is the js fiddle

Comment: Alerts are a horrible user experience for validation. Use icons with tool tips for something more pleasant. Even the standard validation messages are preferable to alerts!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Yes I know that, but I want this in javascript

Comment: The two concepts are not mutually exclusive... ASP.Net provides a whole swathe of validation for you. Why reinvent the wheel (only this time not round)?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Didn't got you.

Comment: e.g. *You can do what I suggest in Javascript too.* Alerts are a very bad choice for user validation and should be reserved for only the most severe problems (if ever used at all).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Yeah, I got your point. But need this way only :(

Comment: @nad yur fiddle is not propper. i cnt see the button in it. :(

Comment: @VP: See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/onkwhhv3/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
  var ErrArr = [];
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         validateTitle();
         validatePrefix();
         validateTextBoxes();
           if(ErrArr.length > 0) {  
             alert(ErrArr.join("\n"));
             ErrArr = [];
             return false;
           }
    });

    function validateTitle() {
        if ($("#ddlTitle").val() > "0") {
            if ($("#ddlTitle").val() == "1104" && $("#txtTitle").val() === "") {
                    ErrArr.push("Please enter the text in other title");

            }

        } else {
             ErrArr.push('Please select the title');

        }           

    }
    function validatePrefix() {
        if ($("#ddlPrefix").val() > "0") {
            if ($("#ddlPrefix").val() == "1110" && $("#txtPrefix").val() === "") {
                ErrArr.push("Please enter the text in other prefix");
            }         


        } else {
           ErrArr.push('Please select the prefix');

        }        

    }
    function validateTextBoxes() {
        if ($("#txtFirstName").val() === "") {
           ErrArr.push('First name is required');

        }
        if ($("#txtMiddleName").val() === "") {
            ErrArr.push('Middle name is required');

        }
        if ($("#txtLastName").val() === "") {
            ErrArr.push('Last name is required');

        }
        if ($("#txtFatherName").val() === "") {
           ErrArr.push('Father name is required');

        }
        if ($("#txtCurrentCompany").val() === "") {
            ErrArr.push('Current company is required');

        }
        if ($("#txtDateofJoin").val() === "") {
            ErrArr.push('Date is required');

        }
        if ($("#txtCurrentExp").val() === "") {
           ErrArr.push('Current Experience is required');

        }           
    }
});
```

Comment: `FrmEmployee_SelfService.aspx:132 Uncaught ReferenceError: Errors is not defined`

Comment: Still getting one by one alert, Not all alert at a time

Comment: have you removed your old code ? as this code will show all error message in one alert

Comment: Yes, i have removed all the code. still getting one by one alert

Comment: Maybe try `validateTitle(); validatePrefix(); validateTextBoxes(); if(ErrArr.length) { ...` so all functions are called. Or maybe the OP is just trolling :D

Comment: ErrArr.join("\n") this line convert array in to string let me update answer suggested by sebastain

Comment: @SebastianNette: I am not trolling here, I just want help.So kindly help if you can but dont comment such type of things. Sorry if I m rude.

Comment: @NishitMaheta: Now this is working for me. Let me check again

Comment: @NishitMaheta: Just one more thing, I want to add one more validation for dropdownlist for this, how to add in the code `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMarritalStatus" runat="server" Width="100">
                    </asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: in which function you want to add this validation?  you can copy validatePrefix() this function and create new one ?

Comment: @NishitMaheta: Its another dropdownlist, so can we create one more function for this and show

Comment: @nad  you can create new function or add in any of this functions . just copy and paste code  and replcae id and message

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using alert all the time, save the message to a variable instead.
Then alert that message after all tests are done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var message = "";

        $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
            message = "";
            if (!validateTitle() || !validatePrefix() || !validateTextBoxes()) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(message);
            }
        });
        function validateTitle() {
            if ($("#ddlTitle").val() > "0") {
                if ($("#ddlTitle").val() == "1104" && $("#txtTitle").val() === "") {
                    message += "Please enter the text in other title\n";
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                message += 'Please select the title\n';
                return false;
            }
        }

        ....
});
```

Comment: Nothing has changed. still the same thing is happening

Comment: I doubt that. All errors are added to the message variable and then alerted all together. If this is not what you wanted then please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following fiddle [JSFiddle][1] , this will basically push all the error messages into an array and can show the results.
Please update if this works for you as i am not aware of markup

Comment: There is a reason they require you to add your code with a JSFiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

> Just a simple trick you can do

just use a string variable for messages appending and counter.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var Messages;
var counter=0;
    $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
        validateTitle();
        validatePrefix();
        validateTextBoxes();
            if(counter > 0)
            {
                alert(Messages);
                e.preventDefault();
                counter=0;
            }
    });
    function validateTitle() {
        debugger;
        if ($("#ddlTitle").val() > "0") {
            if ($("#ddlTitle").val() == "1104" && $("#txtTitle").val() === "") {
                Messages +=  "Please enter the text in other title";
                Messages += "\n";
                counter ++;
            }
        } else {
            Messages +=  'Please select the title';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    function validatePrefix() {
        debugger;
        if ($("#ddlPrefix").val() > "0") {
            if ($("#ddlPrefix").val() == "1110" && $("#txtPrefix").val() === "") {
                Messages +=  "Please enter the text in other prefix";
                Messages += "\n";
                counter ++;
            }
        } else {
            Messages +=  'Please select the prefix';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    function validateTextBoxes() {
        debugger;
        if ($("#txtFirstName").val() === "") {
            Messages +=  'First name is required';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
        if ($("#txtMiddleName").val() === "") {
            Messages +=  'Middle name is required';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
        if ($("#txtLastName").val() === "") {
            Messages +=  'Last name is required';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
        if ($("#txtFatherName").val() === "") {
            Messages +=  'Father name is required';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
        if ($("#txtCurrentCompany").val() === "") {
            Messages +=  'Current company is required';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
        if ($("#txtDateofJoin").val() === "") {
            Messages +=  'Date is required';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
        if ($("#txtCurrentExp").val() === "") {
            Messages +=  'Current Experience is required';
            Messages += "\n";
            counter ++;
        }
    }
});
```

> Just update counter and impliment check if check > 0 show message
>   (alert)
>
> it will benefit you two things

1. User dont need to click each time and get alert.. dont need to
   return false.user Must know at once what erors are in form.
2. Secondly code is simple/Simple logic.

Comment: Might want to reset that counter and message or else you will never be able to submit ater you failed once.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  var Errors = [];
        $('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
            if (!validateTitle() || !validatePrefix() || !validateTextBoxes()) {

                if(Errors.length > 0) {
                    alert(Errors.join("\n"));
                } 
                 e.preventDefault();

            }
        });

        function validateTitle() {
            if ($("#ddlTitle").val() > "0") {
                if ($("#ddlTitle").val() == "1104" && $("#txtTitle").val() === "") {
                    Errors.push("Please enter the text in other title");

                }
                return true;
            } else {
                Errors.push('Please select the title');

            }
        }
        function validatePrefix() {
            if ($("#ddlPrefix").val() > "0") {
                if ($("#ddlPrefix").val() == "1110" && $("#txtPrefix").val() === "") {
                    Errors.push("Please enter the text in other prefix");

                }
                return true;
            } else {
               Errors.push('Please select the prefix');

            }
        }
        function validateTextBoxes() {
            if ($("#txtFirstName").val() === "") {
               Errors.push('First name is required');

            }
            if ($("#txtMiddleName").val() === "") {
                Errors.push('Middle name is required');

            }
            if ($("#txtLastName").val() === "") {
                Errors.push('Last name is required');

            }
            if ($("#txtFatherName").val() === "") {
               Errors.push('Father name is required');

            }
            if ($("#txtCurrentCompany").val() === "") {
                Errors.push('Current company is required');

            }
            if ($("#txtDateofJoin").val() === "") {
                Errors.push('Date is required');

            }
            if ($("#txtCurrentExp").val() === "") {
               Errors.push('Current Experience is required');

            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Add perfect separation in each message to differentiate it.

Comment: are you sure this will work ??   as `return false;` stop code and not check for next validation ?

Comment: @VP: This is not the answer what I want.

Comment: @nad, than please explain VP what it is you are looking for. A comment such as "this is not the answer what I want" doesn't help anyone further.

Comment: @NishitMaheta. oops  i dint noticed it.. thnkx for pointing it. i hve made edits

Comment: @LinkinTED: I have mentioned it that I want all alert message to be shown on a **single alert**